# DIY DNS Appliance

Tags: dns, bind, router

I do a lot of web-app development on multiple platforms: Java, PHP and ASP.net. To keep work separate I like to run any app I happen to be developing under its own domain name on my local intranet, e.g. "peter.example.com", "paul.example.com" & "mary.example.com".

For about a year I've been running [BIND](https://www.isc.org/software/bind/) and very happy to edit my own zone files and whatnot. However running this service causes long bootups so I want to move this off my dev box soon.

This got me to wondering if there's a project like DD-WRT out there that would let me flash an old router to run BIND from it.

Does anyone out there know of any homebrew DNS appliances?

Answer (score 1):

Try [OpenWRT](https://www.openwrt.org/), it's a GNU/Linux distribution tailored for routers that has a rather large set of packages available for it. This includes BIND, which I'm using on my own router as caching DNS resolver specifically to have DNSSEC up and running.

PS This question would probably have been better on serverfault or maybe superuser.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I come to stackoverflow.com by habit! As for OpenWRT, it's a decent candidate, but if I'm going to go to the trouble of replacing my current DNS service with an appliance, I'm going to hang in there for "Bind" as I already have the zone files written! Current plan is to use a Raspberry Pi board with Debian.